# stored procedure in mysql in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux

I have created stored procedure in MySQL in Window-7. it run successfully on windows. But when I switch to Ubuntu it gives error in the stored procedure. On windows I am using SQLyog for creating stored procedure. On Ubuntu, I run the SQL script and call that stored procedure but it gives error. Below is my stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `adserver`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getDaypartTimeDetail`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getDaypartTimeDetail`
(currentDate DATE,noOfdays INT,cityId BIGINT)
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE dateCnt INT;
SET dateCnt = 0;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS OnlyDate;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS AdvScheduleData;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE OnlyDate(dday DATE); 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AdvScheduleData(dday BIGINT,daypartId INT,totalFile BIGINT,totalDur BIGINT); 

/* Generate Dates */
WHILE(dateCnt < noOfdays) DO
    SET i = 1;
    INSERT INTO OnlyDate(dday) VALUES (DATE_ADD(currentDate, INTERVAL dateCnt DAY));
SET dateCnt = dateCnt + 1;
END WHILE;

/* Insert all dayparts for all dates */ 
INSERT INTO AdvScheduleData (dday, daypartID) SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dday)*1000), id FROM OnlyDate, daypart;
/* Update total files and duration */       
UPDATE AdvScheduleData SET 
    TotalFile =    (SELECT COUNT(advt_id) 
            FROM adv_schedule AdvSch
            INNER JOIN advertisement Adv ON Adv.id = AdvSch.advt_id
              WHERE AdvScheduleData.dday BETWEEN AdvSch.start_date AND AdvSch.end_date
              AND AdvSch.status = 2
              AND AdvSch.active = 1
              AND AdvSch.id IN (SELECT schedule_id FROM schedule_daypart 
               WHERE daypart_id = AdvScheduleData.daypartId )
              AND AdvSch.id IN (SELECT schedule_id FROM schedule_cities WHERE city_id = cityId)
              AND Adv.is_active = 1 
              AND Adv.is_deleted = 0
              AND Adv.status = 2 
              AND Adv.expiry_date >= AdvScheduleData.dday),
    totalDur =    (SELECT SUM(Adv.duration)
            FROM adv_schedule AdvSch
            INNER JOIN advertisement Adv ON Adv.id = ADVSCH.advt_id
              WHERE AdvScheduleData.dday BETWEEN AdvSch.start_date AND AdvSch.end_date
              AND AdvSch.status = 2
              AND AdvSch.active = 1
              AND AdvSch.id IN (SELECT schedule_id FROM schedule_daypart 
               WHERE daypart_id = AdvScheduleData.daypartId )
              AND AdvSch.id IN (SELECT schedule_id FROM schedule_cities WHERE city_id = cityId)
              AND Adv.is_active = 1 
              AND Adv.is_deleted = 0
              AND Adv.status = 2 
              AND Adv.expiry_date >= AdvScheduleData.dday);
SELECT * FROM AdvScheduleData;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The output I get in Ubuntu is

> mysql> call getDaypartTimeDetail('2012-08-13',5,30534); ERROR 1054
>   (42S22): Unknown column 'ADVSCH.advt_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Sounds like the adv_schedule table is different on your two instances. Could you paste the output of "desc adserver.adv_schedule;" from both?

Comment: are you sure you are connected to the same database and querying the same tables?

Comment: yes i am using same database, @Kadaan this procedure is perfectly running on windows, It gives correct output. no error in windows.

Comment: The error is saying that there's no "advt_id" column in the adv_schedule table on your Ubuntu box. It doesn't appear to be a problem with the stored procedure but rather with the table structure. It could be a local vs remote permissions issue; does "show grants;" give you the exact same output when run on both boxes?

Comment: @Kadaan  by doing, desc adv_schedule it shows advt_id in the table

Comment: From Ubuntu are you connecting to server as root? Try removing the DEFINER clause in create procedure and running the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table name and aliases are case sensitive in Ubuntu.

Hence, this reference is giving an error:

```
totalDur =    (SELECT SUM(Adv.duration)
        FROM adv_schedule AdvSch
        INNER JOIN advertisement Adv ON Adv.id = ADVSCH.advt_id
```

Change it to `AdvSch.advt_id`